# How to display multiplication result in a textbox using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium

I am a manual tester and want to switch to automation testing. I've learnt Selenium WebDriver recently. While practicing, I came across a webpage where I was asked to automate the following thing in a web form:

In the form, they have provided two double numbers and have asked us to display the multiplication of thosenumbers in the textbox. Please guide me how can I display the result in the textbox using selenium webdriver.

[Screenshot of the xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWg9R.jpg)

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If the two double numbers are in separate input field (any other place except input filed) get the data as follows:

```
double number01 = Double.parseDouble(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your selector for element")).getText());

double number02 = Double.parseDouble(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your selector for element2")).getText());
```

Then perform multiplication and use sendkeys to input into the output field:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your selector for element2")).sendKeys((number01 * number02) + "");
```

**Note:**

Above answer is based on assumption according to your question.

**Edit:**

```
String terms = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(("#form > form > label:nth-child(89)"))).getText().replaceAll("=", "");//get the expression for multiplication and remove the '=' sign at the end
String [] temp_xy = terms.split("X"); // split the string into multiplicand  and multiplier parts
double multiplicand = Double.parseDouble(temp_xy[0].trim());
double multiplier = Double.parseDouble(temp_xy[1].trim());
double product = multiplicand * multiplier;
```

Now, you put your **product** in the desired filed. Similarly, you can find the **quotient**.

Comment: The two numbers are not in separate input fields. E.g. they have given (14.867*67.902) and then below this they have provided a textbox and are expecting to display the result of the multiplication in the textbox.

Comment: Thanks Hemant on guiding me how to attach screenshots. Also thanks Optimist_creeper for helping me. I've added the required screenhshot. Please check and help me in resolving my query. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the HTML for (x*y) part?

Comment: Here is the xpath of the (x*y) part: //*[@id='form']/form/label[11]. Also PFA the screenshot of the xpath for your reference.

Comment: Could anyone please help me in resolving my query? I am stuck due to this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, your comment was not that helpful. If possible, you may give the url.

Comment: Here is the url: http://www.techno-geek.co.uk/SeleniumPractice/webform1.html Please help me out with this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please help me understand exactly what you've done here? (Since I am a beginner, I am asking this to you. Sorry for that.)

Comment: Basically I could not understand the meaning of 1. 'label:nth-child(89)' in the CSS path that you've mentioned. Also it is getting difficult for me to understand 2. the use of split and parsedouble. I am trying to understand the same, meanwhile it would be great if you could explain it to me.

Comment: Hi...I understood what you've done. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hey Opptimist_Creeper: Sorry to ask this question (since I'd already confirmed that I understood the solution provided by you): Could you please explain how did you derive "nth-child(89)" while getting the expression for the multiplication? I tried googling the nth-child concept, but somehow unable to understand it. Your help would be really helpful.

Comment: visit the url for your query: https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors

Answer (score 0):

Add screen shot using below steps-

1. Click "Edit" to your question.
2. On upper side you can find Image icon or press "Ctrl + G".
3. Drag & drop the image or attach by providing the path.

[Note: I have added this as an answer because I don't have 50 points yet to add a comment. Forgive me for that.. :)]